# Creating a "color scale" using vba (avoiding conditional formatting)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2013

I'm looking for a way to apply a color scale to a set of cells via VBA code **but not** by applying some conditional formatting... I want to apply them as static colors (InteriorColor)

I've searched plenty of excel sites, google and stackoverflow and found nothing :(

For my situation if you look at the following picture:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/j8ov4FJ.png]

You can see I've given it a color scale, in this example though I have done the color scale via Conditional formatting. I want to create the color scale via VBA **but it must avoid using conditional formatting**, I want to assign interior colors to the cells so that the colors are static which makes them visible on all mobile excel viewers, faster, won't change if I was to remove any numbers/rows.

Here are some example data **Just save it in a csv and open it in excel to see the data in excel :P**:

```
Data 1 (Yes there are blanks),Data 2,Data 3,Data 4,Data 5,Data 6
155.7321504,144.6395913,1,-4,-9.3844,0.255813953
113.0646481,120.1609771,5,-2,-2.5874,0.088082902
126.7759917,125.3691519,2,0,-0.0004,0.107843137
,0,7,,,0.035714286
123.0716084,118.0409686,4,0,0.3236,0.118881119
132.4137536,126.5740362,3,-2,-3.8814,0.090909091
70,105.9874422,6,-1,-0.3234,0.103896104
```

**I do use the following in python but obviously I can't use this code in VBA**, the following code successfully assigns hex colors to the numbers from a predefined array of 50 colors so it's pretty accurate.

```
def mapValues(values):
    nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
    mask = (nValues != '')
    maskedValues = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in nValues[mask]]
    colorMap = np.array(['#F8696B', '#F86E6C', '#F8736D', '#F8786E', '#F97E6F', '#F98370', '#F98871', '#FA8E72', '#FA9373', '#FA9874', '#FA9E75', '#FBA376', '#FBA877', '#FBAD78', '#FCB379', '#FCB87A', '#FCBD7B', '#FCC37C', '#FDC87D', '#FDCD7E', '#FDD37F', '#FED880', '#FEDD81', '#FEE382', '#FEE883', '#FCEB84', '#F6E984', '#F0E784', '#E9E583', '#E3E383', '#DCE182', '#D6E082', '#D0DE82', '#C9DC81', '#C3DA81', '#BDD881', '#B6D680', '#B0D580', '#AAD380', '#A3D17F', '#9DCF7F', '#96CD7E', '#90CB7E', '#8ACA7E', '#83C87D', '#7DC67D', '#77C47D', '#70C27C', '#6AC07C', '#63BE7B'])
    _, bins = np.histogram(maskedValues, 49)
    try:
        mapped = np.digitize(maskedValues, bins)
    except:
        mapped = int(0)
    nValues[mask] = colorMap[mapped - 1]
    nValues[~mask] = "#808080"
    return nValues.tolist()
```

Anyone have any ideas or has anyone done this before with VBA.

Comment: That's the thing guys, I don't have the hex colors in cells... I have numbers and I can't get to the hex colors stage

Comment: @Smandoli This could be applicable to a large audience as it's trying to do a conditional formatting color scale **which is a commonly used function**  but via vba to make the conditional formatting 100% mobile compatible and to make it faster, static and better in some circumstances. You try and open a sheet that has conditional formatting color scales in Google Sheets and none of them will work where as if you had a vba script to add the colors to the correct scale it would be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the correct answer, it's actually rather simple. All you have to do is add conditional formatting and then set the  `.Interior.Color` to the same as what the `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` is and then delete the conditional formatting.

This will do exactly what is requested in the main post; and if you want to do it as a fallback then just don't delete the conditional formatting.

```
' Select Range
Range("A2:A8").Select

' Set Conditional
Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

' Set Static
For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
    Selection.Cells(i).Interior.Color = Selection.Cells(i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
Next

' Delete Conditional
Selection.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 12):

The following function CalcColorScale will return a color given any two colors and the scale.The scale is the value of your current data relative to the range of data. e.g. if your data is from 0 to 200 then a data value 100 would be scale 50%(.5)

The image shows the result of scaling between red and blue

[image]

```
Public Sub Test()
    ' Sets cell A1 to background purple
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Interior.Color = CalcColorScale(rgbRed, rgbBlue, 0.5)
End Sub

' color1: The starting color as a long
' color2: The end color as a long
' dScale: This is the percentage in decimal of the color.
Public Function CalcColorScale(color1 As Long, color2 As Long, dScale As    Double) As Long

    ' Convert the colors to red, green, blue components
    Dim r1 As Long, g1 As Long, b1 As Long
    r1 = color1 Mod 256
    g1 = (color1 \ 256) Mod 256
    b1 = (color1 \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256

    Dim r2 As Long, g2 As Long, b2 As Long
    r2 = color2 Mod 256
    g2 = (color2 \ 256) Mod 256
    b2 = (color2 \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256

    CalcColorScale = RGB(CalcColorScaleRGB(r1, r2, dScale) _
                        , CalcColorScaleRGB(g1, g2, dScale) _
                        , CalcColorScaleRGB(b1, b2, dScale))
End Function

' Calculates the R,G or B for a color between two colors based the percentage between them
' e.g .5 would be halfway between the two colors
 Public Function CalcColorScaleRGB(color1 As Long, color2 As Long, dScale As Double) As Long
    If color2 < color1 Then
        CalcColorScaleRGB = color1 - (Abs(color1 - color2) * dScale)
    ElseIf color2 > color1 Then
        CalcColorScaleRGB = color1 + (Abs(color1 - color2) * dScale)
    Else
        CalcColorScaleRGB = color1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Oh man, I've just finished the exact same concept I've been working for over half an hour (only less pretty), now I feel useless :D You got my vote, I didn't even know you can do this "b1 = (color1 \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256" to get RGB components, cool.

Comment: Thanks. Glad you like it,

Comment: @PaulKelly Your example picture looks correct however I can't figure out how to use your code for my example data. I tried the following but it didn't work: `Sheet1.Range("A2:A8").Interior.Color = CalcColorScale(248105107, 9910123, 0.5)`

Comment: The code I provided will return a color based on a scale. You need to determine your scale. In your example cells A2:A8 have a range from 13 to 38. Therefore your scale for Cell A2 (with value 32) would be approx .75. You need to go through each cell and pass CalcColorScale the appropriate range based on the value in that cell.

Comment: @PaulKelly That's going straight over my head, not sure why I am not understanding...

Comment: Do you understand how color scaling works? The color of each cell is  based on the value in the cell relative to the maximum and minimum data values.

Comment: @PaulKelly Of course, but I can't figure out how to use your code. I want to create 3 tier color scales for example: http://i.imgur.com/to23RZv.png and just look at my python version which generates hex colors which can be used for tables exactly the same as excels conditionl formatting (al-beit slightly less accurate). I just dont understand why you say that I need to find the scale  (0.75) and can't get the code to color the cells correctly.

Comment: @PaulKelly this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/lq5qCvZ.png under every circumstance, it just turns out purple. :/

Comment: @PaulKelly, great solution but it requires some tests (you get +1 from me). @Ryflex, it is possible to get 3 color scales... put numbers from 0 to 100 step 5 in any column >> run loop for each cell with values >>`If Cell < 50 Then :
Cell.Interior.Color = CalcColorScale(vbRed, vbYellow, Cell / 50) : Else :
Cell.Interior.Color = CalcColorScale(vbYellow, vbGreen, (Cell - 50) / 50) : End If` As a result I have colors from red (0) >> through yellow (50) >> to green (100).

Comment: If you are interested in varying the colour based on luminance only, I have just posted an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35624586/1011724

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the python script to generate the hex colors based of csv data and then simply read the csv file holding the generated hex colors and convert rgb then set the interiorcolor to that of the rgb outcome.

```
Sub HexExample()
    Dim i as Long
    Dim LastRow as Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = HexConv(Cells(i, "A"))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function HexConv(ByVal HexColor As String) As String
    Dim Red As String
    Green As String
    Blue As String
    HexColor = Replace(HexColor, "#", "")
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))

    HexConv = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
```

Comment: Well that's better than all of the other suggestions, with exception of my own answer. How would you suggest to match the data in order to apply the hex colors?

Comment: Not the best of ideas but just do it by row number and then a csv format so `(1,#FFFFFF,null,#000000)` for example would set row a1 to white, b1 to no fill and c1 to black. This way it's not complicated and can easily be modified. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above should work. Still, the color is different that from Excel...

To recreate exact the same thing as Excel color formatting, and a little more straight forward in code:

rgb(cr,cg,cb)

color1: red - rgb(248,105,107)

color2:green - rgb(99,190,123)

color3: blue - rgb(255,235,132)

code:

```
Sub HeatMapOnNOTSorted()

Dim val_min, val_max, val_mid As Double
Dim cr, cg, cy As Double


Dim mysht As Worksheet
Dim TargetRgn As Range

Set mysht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set TargetRgn = mysht.Range("c4:d9") '<-Change whatever range HERE

'get the min&max value of the range
val_min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(TargetRgn)
val_max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(TargetRgn)
val_mid = 0.5 * (val_min + val_max)


For Each rgn In TargetRgn

    ' three color map min-mid-max
    ' min -> mid: green(99,190,123)-> yellow(255,235,132)
        If rgn.Value <= val_mid Then
            cr = 99 + (255 - 99) * (rgn.Value - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
            cg = 190 + (235 - 190) * (rgn.Value - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
            cb = 123 + (132 - 123) * (rgn.Value - val_min) / (val_mid - val_min)
        Else
    ' mid->max: yellow(255,235,132) -> red(248,105,107)
            cr = 255 + (248 - 255) * (rgn.Value - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)
            cg = 235 + (105 - 235) * (rgn.Value - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)
            cb = 132 + (107 - 132) * (rgn.Value - val_mid) / (val_max - val_mid)

        End If
    rgn.Interior.Color = RGB(cr, cg, cb)


Next rgn

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub a()
    Dim vCM As Variant

    vCM = Array("F8696B", "FED880", "63BE7B") ' as many as you need
    ' Array's lower bound is 0 unless it is set to another value using Option Base
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(CStr(vCM(2))) ' off-green in the active cell
End Sub
```

If you deside to forgo the Hex and use the color  values then the above becomes this

```
Sub b()
    Dim vCM As Variant

    vCM = Array(16279915, 16701568, 6536827) ' as many as you need
    ' Array's lower bound is 0 unless it is set to another value using Option Base
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vCM(2) ' 6536827 setts an off-green in the active cell
End Sub
```

In case you do not know how to get the color values, here is the manual process:

1. Apply an interior color to a cell. Make sure the cell is selected.
2. In the VBE's Immediate window, execute `?ActiveCell.Interior.Color` to get the color number for the interior color you've applied in Step 1.

Good luck.

Comment: that doesn't really help, I can't figure out how to even get ot the hex stage even though I have one in python to reference.

Comment: @ryflex What's "the hex stage"?!

Comment: The part that decides what color to use... lets say you have `A1:A15` with numbers in it, you can easily create a conditional formatting rule to put the appropriate colors on the cells but how can i get them the same colour via vba WITHOUT using conditional formatting?

Comment: It's not all wrong at all, that python bit of code ranks numerical data and assigns it a hex color which is the same thing I want for VBA, in this case it can be hex, excel's `interior.color`s or rgb. My first line of my post sums it up in one easy phrase: `I'm looking for a way to apply a color scale to a set of cells via VBA code but not by applying some conditional formatting... I want to apply them as static colors (InteriorColor)` If you check my edit on my post, you'll see I've added a screenshot example.

Comment: @Ryflex I've read your edit (thank you for it)--that's how I finally understood what you wanted. I do not know python to be _sure_ of what your python code is doing. If you do, please rephrase the requirements in plain English (based on the 'edit' image you've provided). My questions in the above comment remain unanswered to me at this point.

Comment: it's... impossible for me to explain it any easier than the screenshot and what I've said lol

Comment: oh, come on! Are the values you evaluate between 13 and 32, or 1 to 100, or -12 to 123, etc.? Is the scale linear or something else? Do you have the colors picked or not? Are there a fixed number of colors?... Do you think all this (and more) has nothing to do with how your problem is to be soved? really?!

Comment: Oh you were meaning what sort of data, well I re-edited my topic and added some example data, as for the colors I want to do it exactly the same as how excel does it so I assume that's linear? I can give you the three exact colors I want to use for the 3 bar color scale (as used in my screenshot) but I'm also ok using a less accurate scale based on a histogram like my python code and provide a list of 50 interior colors. The problem can't be solved as the main reason I want it is so colors are visible in google sheets (conditional formatting is stripped out of) & I dont want to use other apps

Answer (score 0):

assuming:

values in A1:A40.

```
Sub M_snb()
 [a1:A40] = [if(A1:A40="",0,A1:A40)]

 sn = [index(rank(A1:A40,A1:A40),)]
 For j = 1 To UBound(sn)
   If Cells(j, 1) <> 0 Then Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(Int(sn(j, 1) * 255 / 40), Abs(sn(j, 1) > UBound(sn) \ 2), 255 - Int((sn(j, 1) - 1) * (255 / 40)))
 Next

 [a1:A40] = [if(A1:A40=0,"",A1:A40)]
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't form the correct color scheme as shown in my example (248/105/107 = red rgb, 99/190/123 = green rgb, 255/235/132 = yellow rgb), nor does it doesn't ignore the blanks and it also gets the ranking completely wrong. (23 for example has different colors) http://i.imgur.com/rsHjUjL.png

Comment: I only showed you how you can attain the anwer you were looking for. You have my permission to adapt the code. e.g. the adjustment of the colors. To check the ranking : [C1:C40]=[index(rank(A1:A40,A1:A40),)]

Comment: But the color index just uses the palette and assigns the color based on the palette number...

Comment: I changed my code to your wishes. The empty cells have been disregarded.