# VBA: Entering an RGB color using an array

Tags: excel, vba, rgb

I want to colour the chart based on an array input. 
It goes somethinng like this:

```
Public RGB_1            As Variant
Public cht              As ChartObject
Public i                As Integer
Public Ws               As Worksheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

RGB_1 = Ws.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y)) ' x,y,z defined elsewhere

' Changing colors
With ws
   i = 0
   For Each cht In .ChartObjects
      cht.Activate
      ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB_1(i + 1, 1) ' Color from RGB Array in the main sheet
      i = i + 1
   Next cht
 End with
```

The chart can either have 1 or 2 different colours, here I am just using 1 as an example.  The RGB array refers to cells that contain "RGB(xxx, yyy, zzz)" where xxx,yyy,zzz are integers.
When running my sub I get a type mismatch error. I assume I cannot input a cell value, so how do I instead base the colors on an array? 
For the first iteration RGB_1 = "RGB(229,35,49)" (using the watch list in VBA).

Comment: First, add the worksheet reference: `RGB_1 = Ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, y), ws.Cells(z, y))`.  Also, `RGB` is expecting `(#, #, #)`.  What does `RGB_1` look like?

Comment: `i` is only ever going to equal 0 - what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Are you saying your sheet has values like "RGB(229,35,49)" in the area being read into `RGB_1` ?  That's not going to work.  You would be better off setting the cell background colors, and then reading those directly to set the plot colors

Comment: @ScottCraner But he resets `i` to 0 every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @dwirony yup skipped right over that.

Comment: "here I am just using 1 as an example" - I don't think this is intended to be a full solution

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624585/coloring-each-point-of-a-chart-based-on-data-using-sequential-or-divergent-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the cell background colors, and then read those directly to set the plot colors:

```
Public rngColors        As Range
Public cht              As ChartObject
Public i                As Long
Public Ws               As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

With ws

   'note: fully-reference all Range/Cells
    Set rngColors = .Range(.Cells(x, y), .Cells(z, y)) ' x,y,z defined elsewhere

   For Each cht In .ChartObjects
      i = 1 
      cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                      rngColors.Cells(i).Interior.Color       
      i = i + 1
   Next cht
 End with
```

Comment: Thank you some of it to my original code and it works